# Inequality needed in molecular dynamics

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lipschitz-functions

$\newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{#1}{#2}}$
$\newcommand{\nor}[2]{ \left| \! \left| #1 \right| \! \right|_{#2} }$
$\newcommand{\ab}[1]{\left|#1\right|}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\pa}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}$
$\def\1{1}$

Consider the norm
\begin{align*}
 \nor{V}{L^{\f{3}{2}}(\R^3) + L^\infty(\R^3)} := {\underset{\substack{V_{3/2} \in L^{\f{3}{2}  }(\R^3) \\ V_{\infty} \in L^\infty(\R^3) \\ V = V_{3/2} + V_\infty}}{\text{inf}}\quad} \pa{\nor{V_{3/2}}{L^{\f{3}{2}}} + \nor{V_\infty}{L^\infty(\R^3)}}
\end{align*}
which defines a Banach space. It enables to treat local singularities since $\ab{\cdot}^{-p} \in L^{\f{3}{2}} + L^\infty$ for any $p < 2$, by decomposing $\ab{\cdot}^{-p} = \ab{\cdot}^{-p} \1_{\ab{\cdot} \le c}  + \ab{\cdot}^{-p}\1_{\ab{\cdot} \ge c}$ (the first function is in $L^{\f{3}{2}}$ and the second in $L^{\infty}$) but $\ab{\cdot}^{-p} \notin L^{\f{3}{2}}$. But $\ab{\cdot}^{-2} \notin L^{\f{3}{2}} + L^\infty$. My question is, do we have
\begin{align*}
 \nor{ \ab{r-\cdot}^{-1} - \ab{\cdot}^{-1}  }{L^{\f{3}{2}} + L^\infty} \le c \ab{r} 
\end{align*}
for any $r \in \R^3$, where $c$ does not depend on $r$ ? Of course it's when $r$ is small that there is an issue.

At first sight, it is natural to do
\begin{align}\label{eqq}
 \ab{\ab{r-x}^{-1} - \ab{x}^{-1}} &= \ab{\ab{r-x} - \ab{x}}\ab{r-x}^{-1}\ab{x}^{-1} \nonumber \\
       & \le \ab{r} \ab{r-x}^{-1}\ab{x}^{-1}
\end{align}
but then $\nor{\ab{r-\cdot}^{-1}\ab{\cdot}^{-1}}{L^{\f{3}{2}} + L^\infty}$ is not bounded in $r$ when $r$ is small, since
\begin{align*}
\nor{\ab{r-\cdot}^{-1}\ab{\cdot}^{-1}}{L^{\f{3}{2}} + L^\infty} \rightarrow +\infty
\end{align*}
when $\ab{r} \rightarrow 0$. But for any $\varepsilon > 0$ small,
\begin{align*}
\ab{r}^\varepsilon \nor{\ab{r-\cdot}^{-1}\ab{\cdot}^{-1}}{L^{\f{3}{2}} + L^\infty} \rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
So is there an approach, which is finer and which yields the result ? Or what is the lowest singularity, that we cannot remove ?

Comment: I believe that you can not do better than $c\,|r|\,(1+|\ln(r)|)$ in general. However, if you know Besov spaces, notice that $1/|x| \in \dot{B}^{1}_{3/2,\infty}$ (see Bahouri, Chemin, Danchin "Fourier Analysis
and Nonlinear Partial
Differential Equations", Prop 2.21), and so by Thm 2.37
$$
\||\cdot-r|^{-1} + |\cdot+r|^{-1} - 2 |\cdot|^{-1}\|_{L^{3/2}} \leq C\,r
$$

Comment: thank you very much for this reference, I didn't know Besov spaces. Unfortunately I cannot use that complicated spaces in my application. Would you have a reference too for the bound in $|r|(1+ ln|r|)$ please ?

Answer (score 1):

As a summary, there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for any $z\in\mathbb R^3$,
$$
\left\|\frac{1}{|x-z|} - \frac{1}{|x|}\right\|_{L^{3/2}_x+L^\infty_x} \leq C\,|z|\left(1+(-\ln(|z|))_+^{2/3}\right)
$$
with $a_+ = \max(a,0)$. If you do not want logarithms to appear, you can consider differences of order $2$, and then by the references indicated in my comment, there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for any $z\in\mathbb R^3$,
$$
\left\|\frac{1}{|x-z|} + \frac{1}{|x+z|} - \frac{2}{|x|}\right\|_{L^{3/2}_x} \leq C\,|z|
$$

---

**Proof of the first formula.** If you do not like complicated spaces, the best strategy in this kind of problems is to cut the integral. One can write $|x|^{-1} = K(x) + \varphi(x)$ with $\varphi(x) = \min(|x|^{-1},1)$ is a bounded Lipschitz function, and $K(x) = (|x|^{-1}-1)_+$. More precisely, $|\nabla\varphi|\leq 1$ so $\|\varphi(\cdot-z)-\varphi\|_{L^\infty}\leq |z|$. The difficulty is to handle $K$. Let me look at $K(x-z)-K(x)$ when $|z|\leq 1/2$, since as you say, the difficulty is when $|z|$ is small. Then by the triangle inequality
$$
I_K := \|K(\cdot-z)-K\|_{L^{3/2}} \leq \left(\int_{|x|\leq 1 \,\&\, |x-z|\leq 1} \left|\frac{1}{|x-z|}-\frac{1}{|x|}\right|^{3/2}\mathrm d x\right)^{2/3}
\\
+ \left(\int_{|x|\geq 1 \,\&\, |x-z|\leq 1} K(x-z)^{3/2}\mathrm d x\right)^{2/3} + \left(\int_{|x-z|\geq 1 \,\&\, |x|\leq 1} K(x)^{3/2}\mathrm d x\right)^{2/3}.
$$
One can do a change of variable $x\mapsto z-x$ in the second integral of the right hand side to get
$$
I_K \leq \left(\int_{|x|\leq 1} \left|\frac{1}{|x-z|}-\frac{1}{|x|}\right|^{3/2}\mathrm d x\right)^{2/3} + 2\left(\int_{|x-z|\geq 1 \,\&\, |x|\leq 1} \left(\frac{1}{|x|}-1\right)^{3/2}\mathrm d x\right)^{2/3}.
$$
Now let me treat each of these two integrals.

***The first integral***

- By your computation, at large distances
  $$
  J_r^c := \int_{r\leq |x|\leq 1} \left|\frac{1}{|x-z|}-\frac{1}{|x|}\right|^{3/2}\mathrm d x \leq |z|^{3/2}\int_{r\leq |x|\leq 1} \frac{\mathrm d x }{|x-z|^{3/2}|x|^{3/2}}.
  $$
  In particular, taking $r = 2\,|z|$ implies that $|z| \leq |x|/2$ in this integral, and so $|x-z|\geq |x|-|z| \geq |x|/2$, from which you get by a polar change of variable
  $$
  J_r^c \leq (2\,|z|)^{3/2}\int_{r\leq |x|\leq 1} \frac{\mathrm d x }{|x|^{3}} = -4\pi\,(2\,|z|)^{3/2} \ln(2\,|z|).
  $$
  Since $2\,|z|\leq 1$, observe that $-\ln(2\,|z|) = \left|\ln(2\,|z|)\right|$
- Now we look at short distances, that is
  $$
  J_r = \int_{|x|\leq r} \left|\frac{1}{|x-z|}-\frac{1}{|x|}\right|^{3/2}\mathrm d x.
  $$
  Here it is sufficient to use the triangle inequality to get
  $$
  J_r^{2/3} \leq \left(\int_{|x|\leq r} \frac{\mathrm d x}{|x|^{3/2}}\right)^{2/3} + \left(\int_{|x|\leq r} \frac{\mathrm d x}{|x-z|^{3/2}}\right)^{2/3}.
  $$
  The first integral is directly given by a polar change of variable and the fact that $r=2\,|z|$ by
  $$
  \left(\int_{|x|\leq r} \frac{\mathrm d x}{|x|^{3/2}}\right)^{2/3} = (4\pi)^{2/3} \left(\int_0^r t^{1/2}\,\mathrm d t\right)^{2/3} =  2\,(8\pi/3)^{2/3} \,|z|.
  $$
  The second can be estimated similarly by first noticing that $|x|\leq r \implies |x-z|\leq r+|z| = 3\,|z|$, hence
  $$
  \left(\int_{|x|\leq r} \frac{\mathrm d x}{|x-z|^{3/2}}\right)^{2/3} \leq \left(\int_{|y|\leq 3|z|} \frac{\mathrm d y}{|y|^{3/2}}\right)^{2/3} =  3\,(8\pi/3)^{2/3} \,|z|.
  $$

Putting these estimates together, we get that the first integral is bounded by
$$
(J_r^c)^{2/3} + J_r^{2/3} \leq (4\pi)^{2/3} \left(5\,(2/3)^{2/3} + 2 \,\left|\ln(2\,|z|)\right|^{2/3}\right) |z|.
$$

***The second integral***

- Notice that $|x-z|\geq 1 \implies |x| \geq 1-|z|\geq 1/2$, and so
  $$
  \int_{|x-z|\geq 1 \,\&\, |x|\leq 1} \left(\frac{1}{|x|}-1\right)^{3/2}\mathrm d x \leq \left(\frac{1}{1-|z|}-1\right)^{3/2} \int_{1/2\leq |x|\leq 1} \mathrm d x
  \\
  \leq \left(\frac{|z|}{2}\right)^{3/2} \frac{7\,\pi}{6}.
  $$

***Conclusion***

For any $|z|\leq 1/2$
$$
\||\cdot-z|^{-1}-|\cdot|^{-1}\|_{L^\infty+L^{3/2}} \leq \|\varphi(\cdot-z)-\varphi\|_{L^\infty} + \|K(\cdot-z)-K\|_{L^{3/2}}
\\
\leq \left(1 + \left(\tfrac{7\,\pi}{6}\right)^{2/3} + (4\pi)^{2/3} \left(5\,(2/3)^{2/3} + 2 \,\left|\ln(2\,|z|)\right|^{2/3}\right)\right) |z|.
$$
The constants are not at all optimal of course. To simplify, this implies that for any $|z|\leq 1/2$
$$
\||\cdot-z|^{-1}-|\cdot|^{-1}\|_{L^\infty+L^{3/2}} \leq 25 \left(1 + \,\left|\ln(|z|)\right|^{2/3}\right) |z|.
$$